# Change cell constraint dynamicly in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, cell

I'm trying to update some constraints on a cell depending on the scroll progress inside my TableView. The goal is to recreate this effect : https://youtu.be/VMyNHq3CO04?t=416 (at 6:56)

I'm currently having all my cell with spaces and rounded corner. For now, I get the position of the offset of the scrollView of my tableView and run the following function :

```
 func updateCellState(position: CGFloat) {
    let numberOfItems = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)
    for i in 0..<numberOfItems {
        guard let cell = tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)) as? FMReceiptReviewCellWithContextualActions else {
            break
        }
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.stretch = position / 1000 > 1 ? 1 : position / 1000
        cell.delegate?.updateCellState(position: position)
        cell.setNeedsLayout()
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

The `updateCellState` take the position of the scrollView to update my constraint proportionally.

But I've some major issues with this code :

- In term of performance, the function is called way to often because of the scrollView (even when calling the `updateCellState` only by 30,40,... offset point)
- My cells are not always updated and they need to be dequeue to be reload and display my cells with new parameters (a `reloadData()` of the tableView work, but not suitable for a smooth flow)

Do you have any idea how I could replicate the effect I mentioned above.

Comment: What's the issue with the frequent calling of this function? Why are cell not always updated? And actually, how you do update?

Comment: The problem is that the cell doesn't reload is layout when scrolling with the current code. I've to do a reloadData(). The problem is that it's suitable for the scrolling effect. Everytime the user will scroll the data will be reload. That is my problem with the frequence of the called